# Is it possible to build this out of soma cube parts?

Tags: geometry, tiling

For those of you who don't know, these are soma cube parts:
[image]
They can be assembled into a 3x3x3 cube.

Is it possible to build a hollow cube with the extra little cube being on top, in the middle of the 3x3x3 cube? (So that it looks like you took the middle little cube that can not be seen in the standard 3x3x3 configuration and put it on top, two layers higher.) You can ignore the pattern on the pieces.

Comment: Do we have to obey the black and white rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution, though I have paid no attention to the checkerboard colouring of the pieces in the picture.

> ```
>  R R V   R V V   T B B
>  R A L   T   B   T S B     S
>  A A L   A S L   T S L
> ```
>
> This is diagrammed as the layers, where each piece is represented by a unique letter placed in each cube the piece occupies.

Comment: Excellent! The pattern doesnt have anything to do with the riddle, I'll add this information.